# Unable to import modules in Orange python environment but Orange GUI works

Tags: orange

I would like to use the `Orange.associate` and `Orange.data.sql` modules in python scripting but in both cases I get AttributeError after `import Orange`.

However, in the Orange GUI both widgets work as expected.

When I check the python path with `sys.path`, the python interpreter has access to the Orange libraries, the global dist-packages and the local site-packages.

I have ubuntu 14.04 running and I installed Orange 3.3 into the `/opt` directory, following the instructions here:
http://orange.biolab.si/download/linux/

I am very unfamiliar with python environments and quite a beginner with Linux as well, so any hint is appreciated.

Here is an example of what I did:

```
(orange3env)bdukai@balazs-dukai:/opt/orange$ python
Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Orange
>>> Orange.data.sql
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sql'
>>> Orange.data.Table
<class 'Orange.data.table.Table'>
```

Comment: What instructions did you follow to install Orange? If this is Orange 3, the associate widgets are from `orangecontrib.associate.widgets`, not `Orange.associate`. Run the GUI with `python -m Orange.canvas -l 4` to get a verbose printout of what is going on.

Comment: I'm using Orange 3.3.3. and I followed the instructions on the Orange website. And my aim is to use the library in python scripts, not from the GUI. See my edited question.

Answer (score 1):

Import in python does not import submodules (subpackages) automatically. If you want to use Orange.data.sql, you should import it directly:

```
>>> import Orange.data.sql
>>> Orange.data.sql
<module 'Orange.data.sql' from '.../Orange/data/sql/__init__.py'>
```